# PAT not translating at all

Tags: routing, nat, cisco-ios, troubleshooting

I am studying for my CCENT. 
I threw together a PAT practice lab.
Other than DHCP and RIP everything is pretty stock. 
No VLANs
No security
Just NAT overload on ACCESS router. 
I am stumped why it isn't translating 
It will still ping all around.
`show ip nat statistics`, miss count is going up.
Debugging for NAT is on but silent.
It all looks like it should be working.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

[image]

```
ACCESS#sho ip nat translations 

ACCESS#sho ip nat stat
Total translations: 0 (0 static, 0 dynamic, 0 extended)
Outside Interfaces: GigabitEthernet0/1
Inside Interfaces: GigabitEthernet0/0
Hits: 0  Misses: 163
Expired translations: 0
Dynamic mappings:

ACCESS#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 981 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname ACCESS
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524DSR5-
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 8.8.8.2
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 8.8.8.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
 version 2
 passive-interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 network 8.0.0.0
 network 10.0.0.0
!
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
access-list 1 permit host 10.0.0.0
!
no cdp run
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the NAT access-list 1 is too tight.  `host 10.0.0.0`  will only match the single host with address `10.0.0.0`, and you have no such host.

You almost certainly wanted this:

```
access-list 1 permit 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255
```

which will include your hosts at the bottom of your diagram.

Comment: The wildcard mask got me. I entered it as a subnet mask. so, was my other traffic going as normal and NAT was just waiting for host 10.0.0.0 to translate?

Comment: Also, can you please tell me how you edited my code to be in it's original format? thanks again

Comment: Re mask: I believe so.  Re formatting: mark some text, click `{ }` in little edit menu.  For inline, use back-ticks.  If you edit the question you'll see it.

Comment: I can't edit, I'm too new., what's a backtick?

Comment: The back-tick is also sometimes called left-single-quote or grave (which I can't type here) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming  You don't type the braces, you click on the braces icon, which isn't obvious to me either.  Or you can type four spaces at the front of each line (and blank lines above and below) a block to mark it like the configs.

Comment: NB: do accept answers if they help, you get a few points and it stops the question coming up as a zombie in a few months time, desperate for an answers!  Of course, add and accept your own answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The access-list configuration seems to be incorrect . Make changes in access-list configuration for existing configuration and check connectivity .

`Router(config)#  access-list permit 1 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255` `any`

`Router(config) ip nat inside source list 1 interfàce G0/1` `overload`